# Are there any red filters that fit an SJ4000

Tags: filter, action-cam

Are there any red filters to fit the SJ4000 camera? Is is possible to use one compatible with a gopro hero 3?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you trying to accomplish with a red filter?  There may be a better way.

Comment: I want to use it for underwater video in blue waters. I have seen the difference it can make by reducing some of the bluey haze and adding more colour and depth to everything else.

Comment: ah, yeah, it will make it a lot darker overall since so little red light gets down that far and you'll be re-balancing light to that low level, but should help with the color imbalance.  It is probably worth adding the fact it needs to work underwater to the question too since it rules out some more hacky solutions.

Comment: it costs more than the sj4000 itself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I can't confirm it.  It appears that people online have had success with using GoPro filters of the type that just slide between the case and the lens.  You could also probably just order some appropriately shaded lighting gel or optical filter material and cut it to size yourself.

Comment: Good point, I didn't think about that.

Comment: @connersz - also, good luck.  Let me know how it turns out.  My wife and I are divers, so I'm always interested in how people are doing underwater shooting.  I've not messed with filters personally because my camera has built in white balance modes for adjusting for the color shift. (I use a Sealife DC1400.)

Comment: I will do. I am also wondering if it would just be easier to do it in post or not and I'm not sure how the camera would cope with the reduced light levels from using the gel.

Comment: @connersz well the problem you run in to with underwater footage is that there is so little of the red channel that it is effectively always zero, so correction after the fact isn't really possible below somewhere around 20 to 40 feet (depends on how clear the water is).  The filter adjusts for this, but it does it by matching green and blue light to the low level of the blue.   It's a trade off between color accuracy and noise. The ideal is to use a light and no filter.

Answer (score 1):

there is a german speaking website that sells sj4000 fitting red and magenta filters if you are still searching:

http://www.magic-filter.de/artikelliste/gruppe/id-004-produkte-fuer-qumox-sj4000.html